# Pattern Matching with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, pattern-matching, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to match a pattern into a string in XSLT/XPath using the matches function, as follows:

```
<xsl:when test="matches('awesome','awe')">
   ...
</xsl:when>
```

However, in both Firefox 3.5.9 and IE8, it doesn't show up. IE8 tells me that "'matches' is not a valid XSLT or XPath function." Is this due to XSLT 2.0 not being supported, and is there a way around this?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a number of useful functions for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regular Expressions are supported only in XSLT 2.x/XPath 2.x**.

As at this date, no publicly available browser supports XSLT 2.x/XPath 2.x.

**In your concrete case you can use**:

```
starts-with('awesome','awe')
```

**other useful XPath 1.0 functions are:**

- `contains()`
- `substring()`
- `substring-before()`
- `substring-after()`
- `normalize-space()`
- `translate()`
- `string-length()`

Comment: Thanks! fn:matches would have been nice, but I think I'll have to make do with contains and customizing my strings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct hint that browsers don't support XSLT/XPath 2.0: note that Firefox (since version 3.0 I think) supports some EXSLT functions, in particular for regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/EXSLT#Regular_expressions so with Firefox you could consider EXSLT functions. For IE using MSXML you could incorporate http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/regexp.match.msxsl.xsl which implements the EXSLT match function using the msxsl:script element.